# How does ruby know where to find rspec in require "rspec"

Tags: ruby, rspec

In Ruby I can require another file using a relative path with `require_relative "file.rb"`

But how come I'm able to write `require 'rspec'` in a random Ruby file and have it know exactly which file I'm referring to?

I understand (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417179/how-does-ruby-know-where-to-find-a-required-file) post) that in rails require is working with $LOAD_PATH to find the file path, but I'm not seeing how it works in some arbitrary directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-do-gems-work/) explains it in detail. Here's the important bits:

> To help you use the code inside of your gems, RubyGems overrides Ruby’s require method. (It does this in [core_ext/kernel_require.rb](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/169b12eb5815784d7ee721186456ad20a004ce71/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L38)). The comment is pretty clear:
>
> ```
>  ##
>   # When RubyGems is required, Kernel#require is replaced with our own which
>   # is capable of loading gems on demand.
>   #
>   # When you call <tt>require 'x'</tt>, this is what happens:
>   # * If the file can be loaded from the existing Ruby loadpath, it
>   #   is.
>   # * Otherwise, installed gems are searched for a file that matches.
>   #   If it's found in gem 'y', that gem is activated (added to the
>   #   loadpath).
>   #
> ```

The rest of the post walks us through the require process step by step, looking through the code; but the gist of it is, if original `require` (through `$LOAD_PATH`) fails, it will scan the specification files of all installed gems and see if your require is supposed to work with it; if so, it activates (adds to `$LOAD_PATH`) that gem and also all gems that it depends on; finally it will re-invoke the original `require`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RubyGems, or `gem install` to install Gems on your computer, `require` will use RubyGems to find the path of the Gem that you have installed on your computer.

Here is a simple script using the [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) gem to explore how it resolves the Rspec path:

```
require 'byebug'

byebug
require 'rspec'
```